# Make Radio Buttons Right To Left in the Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, radio-button

I have a form like this :

[image: Main GUI]

as you see this is a persian form. I want to make radio buttons RIGHT TO LEFT means that i want the radio come first then the comment text of radio appears. I have used this function:

```
private void makeComponentsRightToLeft(){       
        Component[] components = this.getComponents();
        for(Component comp:components){
            if(comp instanceof JComponent){
                comp.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);                
            }            
        }
    }
```

in the constructor of the form. but nothing change, what should I do for this problem?

Thank you for your helping. Ummmm some thing that I forgot is that I use group Layout for my design

Comment: To change orientation of the whole hierarchy use `applyComponentOrientation`. There is also an alignment property to radio buttons (`setHorizontalAlignment`): LEADING for text before button and TRAILING for the converse, but LEADING is the default and is compatible with LTR-RTL switches.

Comment: Thank you @Jean-BaptisteYunès . why did not you write your solution as an asnwer?

Comment: whats happens in the case that you apply RTL to container too

Comment: @mKorbel My form's components re ordered and I should change the order in group layout. I have test `applyComponentOrientation` but `setHorizontalAlignment` was perfect for doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change orientation of the whole hierarchy use applyComponentOrientation. There is also an alignment property to radio buttons (setHorizontalAlignment): LEADING for text before button and TRAILING for the converse, but LEADING is the default and is compatible with LTR-RTL switches.